# treadking live streaming with python

Tags: python

I am trying to call live streaming api from tradeking (https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/node-streaming)

Following is my code:

```
import requests

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1 
CK = "CK" 
CS = "CS" 
OT = "OT" 
OS ="OS"






def read_stream():

   s = requests.Session()
   s.auth = OAuth1(CK, CS, OT, OS, signature_type='auth_header')
   symbols = ["APPL", "GOOG"]
   payload = {'symbols': ','.join(symbols)}
   headers = {'connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': '     application/json', 'x-powered-by': 'Express', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'}

    req = s.get('https://stream.tradeking.com/v1/market/quotes.json',
                       params=payload)

    prepped = s.prepare_request(req)

    resp = s.send(prepped, stream=True)

    for line in resp.iter_lines():
       if line:
          print(line)


 read_stream()
```

Following is my error.
   "ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))"

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the exception is raised in `s.get(...)` which will perform an actual HTTP GET operation and return a `Response` object.

The subsequent lines dealing with prepared requests seem wrong and won't work on `Response` objects, but that code is not being executed due to the exception.

Try adding `stream=True` to the request and then iterate over the response:

```
resp = s.get('https://stream.tradeking.com/v1/market/quotes.json', stream=True, params=payload)

for line in resp.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: ERROR message as follows:                    ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))

Comment: @KppatelPatel: I am unable to replicate that error. What I find is that the streaming API hangs without producing any data, i,e. trade king is not returning data. The API works fine for non-streaming requests. You might like to double check your credentials - you can do that by making a successful request with the non-streaming version: https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/ext/quotes.json